# Why do physical bodies in the universe follow the law of physics ( or any rule/pattern ) ?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, education

Why do physical bodies in universe are bound to follow a rule ( eg. laws of physics ) ? Is their any imaginary condition possible, where they stop following any rule. And everything becomes random ? ( For example, a flying butter fly moves randomly, diseases like cancer occur randomly, then why physical bodies too cannot be random ? Why universe is based on rules ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why should a (physical) principle be applicable to different systems in different positions in space and time?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/123525/). Also related: [This](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/126347/)

Comment: Wouldn't that be more appropriate for Philosophy.SE? Anyway, if physical objects would never follow any rules, then the same would also be true for the physical objects making up our brains (or rather, then not making up our brains, because forming brains also requires following rules), and thus there would be nobody there to observe the universe.

Comment: The main question which is more or less answered in the suggested duplicate. As for the other ones, yes, the universe can become random at any moment, induction might break down and we just do not know when that could happen. However, we do not believe that it will. A butterfly or cancer also follows laws and rules, but the system is so complex and requires so much information to be predicted that we resort to an effective statistical description.

Comment: *A thing can't be what it isn't*.  To exist as *something* is to be something particular and not something else.  These aren't physical laws, these are 'laws' of thought.  An electron, for example, doesn't 'follow' physical law, an electron is simply an electron and not something else.  It is up to us, as rational beings, to discover what being an electron *is*; to discover and *define* the concept "electron".