# Holding the total velocity below speed of light

Tags: special-relativity, electrons, speed-of-light

If a hydrogen atom accelerates to near the speed of light, the total velocity of the system must not exceed that limit. Even if the electron has no net angular momentum around the proton, as it could be ejected from the atom by photoelectric effect, it must have a discrete velocity around the proton. If this velocity doesn't change then it is possible as the atom accelerates that the sum of this velocity and the velocity of the whole atom exceeds the speed of light. How does the system respond to this eventuality? By decreasing the angular velocity of the electron? But how?

Comment: Wouldn't time dilation affect the atom?

Comment: A hydrogen atom in the lab is ultra-relativistic in some inertial frame.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do we know why there is a speed limit in our universe?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/230703/do-we-know-why-there-is-a-speed-limit-in-our-universe)

Comment: The orbiting electron is not an accurate model, but disregarding that: velocities are not additive in Special Relativity. Velocities cannot accumulate to exceed the speed of light. See the link above.

Comment: @AdrianHoward Am I right? : For the proton time is dilated too but we still see it go same speed.. same for the electron.... A hypotethic spaceship going 0.99c is time dilated but the speed is still 0.99c, not less....

Comment: @KrešimirBradvica In the spaceship's frame of reference the atom and c would seem normal, to an external frame, considering the spaceship at 0.99c, it would seem the atoms time frame dilated, giving the relative decrease in angular velocity of the electron. At least this is how I understand it.

Comment: @rghome As that post has really a lot of long answers give me a day to review them. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

While your example with the electron has certain problems because of quantum mechanics, your general question has a simple answer: In special relativity, if $B$ is moving with velocity $u$ relative to $A$, and $C$ is moving with velocity $v$ relative to $B$, then the velocity of $C$ relative to $A$ is *not* simply $u + v$. Instead it is given by the [relativistic formula for velocity addition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity-addition_formula#Special_relativity)
$$ \frac{u + v}{1 + \frac{uv}{c^2}} $$
which you can show is always less than $c$.

Comment: Does the angular velocity of the electron in the FoR of the proton decrease when the proton is accelerating? Thanks.

Comment: Because of quantum mechanics, the concept of "angular velocity" of the electron is not actually well-defined. However, if you were to think about a "classical electron" your question is fine. I'm not sure what would happen _while the proton is accelerating_, but after it has finished accelerating and is moving with a large constant speed relative to us, everything _in the FoR of the proton_ would be the same. That is relativity: The proton can't know if it is moving or not.