# What is the velocity of propagation of the interaction, why is there a "maximum value" of it and how can we calculate this value?

Tags: speed-of-light, interactions

I just started reading Landau's *Classical Theory of Fields* and it starts by mentioning how the change in one particle will affect another particle interacting with the first one after some non zero amount of time, and immediately after that, that this velocity will be **the maximum** velocity of propagation of the interaction (signal velocity).
I don't understand *what do we compare this velocity to*, argueing that it has to be *the maximum* signal velocity, and why should there be a maximum value of it. What other propagations of interaction are there that have a different velocity?

Comment: [Do we know why there is a speed limit in our universe?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/230703/37364)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do we know why there is a speed limit in our universe?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/230703/)